# Unity3D is giving me unexpected output: Instantiating objects at too high of a rate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright, so I'm making a game in Unity, and I tried to spawn in enemies randomly around a player. To control the rate of the spawning, I created a `private bool spawnCooldown` variable. Then, there was an `if {}` statement which controlled the rate of spawning. The original code is below:

```
private bool spawnCooldown;

private void Start
{
    spawnCooldown = Time.time;
}

private void Update
{
    if (spawnCooldown < Time.time)
    {
        Instantiate(original, position, rotation);
        spawnCooldown = Time.time + 3f;
        // Note that original, position and rotation are just placeholders 
        // and not the actual code.
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Currently, it's just instantiating every frame update, and it seems that it's not testing the if  statement at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the seconds of cooldown you want on the spawner when you declare it too, E.G  `spawnCooldown = Time.time + coolDownPeriodInSeconds;`

You also need to set `spawnCooldown` to be a float, which stores numbers.
Currently you have stored it as a `bool`, which only stores `true` or `false` values, and therefore cannot be compared to Time.time further in the code.

Lastly you are missing the closing `}` character in the `if` block

What is happening currently is you are doing the following:

1. Setting spawn Cooldown to be the current Time
2. For every frame after that, checking if the new current time is greater than the old time you set as `spawnCooldown`. Since it always is, the code will then run through the spawn script.

If you change it to

```
private float spawnCooldown;
void Start
{
    spawnCooldown = Time.time +3f ;
}
void Update
{
 

    if (spawnCooldown < Time.time)
    {
        Instantiate(original, position, rotation);
        spawnCooldown = Time.time + 3f;
    }
        //Note that original, position and rotation are just placeholders and not the actual code.

}
```

Then it works fine.

Good luck with Unity!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it should work, but Unity must be just bugging out. I logged ```spawnCooldown < Time.time``` and it returns false, but I don't know why the code inside the if statement is still running.

Comment: @Alanduan lmao- you're missing a `}` after the if block!

Comment: @Alanduan I've edited my post as such x'D

Comment: @Alanduan no problem dude. If you've got a GitHub you'll post this to let me know it, I'm always down to try hobby-Unity games

Comment: I haven't said much in a while, I will definitely give you my github when I'm done!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to fix the problems with StarshipladDev's answer. The problem was that the clones were cloning themselves, as I was instantiating the gameobject itself.